# Как вставить дату в формате dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm в БД

Tags: c#, sql-server, дата

Есть `Sql Server`. Есть поле типа `datetime2`. Пробую добавить текущую дату со временем.

```
var dataOpening = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")    
 sql.Parameters.Add("@ДатаОткрытия", SqlDbType.Date, 100);
 sql.Parameters["@ДатаОткрытия"].Value = dataOpening;
```

В итоге в таблицу записываются такие данные

```
2015-10-28 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По поводу потери времени: у вас указан тип параметра Date, а нужно DateTime:

```
sql.Parameters.Add("@ДатаОткрытия", SqlDbType.DateTime);
```

Если же говорить о формате даты, то формат `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` -- строковый. У вас же, скорее всего, колонка в БД типа DateTime. Нет никакой нужды делать ее строковой и писать туда дату в определенном формате.